# Error writing WHEN THEN to IF THEN

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, case-when

The following `WHEN THEN` works well in `PostgreSQL`,

```
SELECT
      CASE WHEN ab.col1='NULL' THEN ab.col2  ELSE ab.col1 END as col
FROM table1 as ab
```

I need to have `ELSE IF` in the statement, so I tried converting to a simple `IF THEN` as follows,

```
SELECT
      IF ab.col1='NULL' THEN ab.col2  ELSE ab.col1 END IF as col
FROM table1 as ab
```

But this gives an error,

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 2: IF ab.col1='NULL' then ab.col2 ELSE ab.col1...
             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 13
```

Can you please help me to sort this out?

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL

Comment: Why do you need to switch to `IF`? What? This makes no sense.

Comment: @JNevill I need to use `ELSE IF`

Comment: WHY DO YOU NEED TO USE ELSE IF though? Or, maybe more to the point, what is wrong with your CASE statement that you feel you need to change it? What are you trying to do? This feels very much like [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Just put the next `WHEN` clause in there.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the [postgresql.org](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) talks about `IF THEN` statements in Postgresql

Comment: IF/END IF is only valid (in PG) in plpgsql

Comment: @Shana That is for Functions in Postgres. You are writing a SQL Statement though, not a function.

Comment: @TrippKinetics does `WHEN` works as `ELSE IF`? i.e. does second `WHEN` statement executes only if the first fails and it doesn't go to second `WHEN` if the first one satisfies?

Comment: @Shana before you start building complex `WHEN` clauses, I would suggest you take a look at functions using `plpgsql` or `anonymous code blocks` to implement your conditions. WHEN can quickly become very dirty when dealing with complex conditions.

Comment: @Shana Yes. That's precisely what `CASE` statements are for.

Comment: @Shana that is PL/pgSQL, not SQL

Comment: Why don't you take a step back and tell us the actual problem you are trying to solve? Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do :

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN ab.col1='NULL THEN ab.col2  
          ELSE ab.col1 END as col
FROM table1 as ab;
```

Not sure for you NULL to be really a string ... or you can do :

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN ab.col1 IS NULL THEN ab.col2  
          ELSE ab.col1 END as col
FROM table1 as ab;
```

Hope this will help.